# Polarization vector of chiral light

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, chirality

I was curious about the following point: let's say we have a left circularly polarized light wavepacket travelling from left to right. We will call its polarization vector $\epsilon_{L}$ while the polarization vector for the right polarized light will be called $\epsilon_{R}=\epsilon^{*}_{L}$. What will the polarization vectors be in the case of a wavepacket propagating from right to left for the two different polarizations? (As written in terms of the $\epsilon_{L}$ and $\epsilon_{R}$ described before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question stems from the following property: any rotation of the point of view or of the field, does not change the polarization. Therefore, applying a $\pi$ rotation of the field along an axis perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$, we see that $\mathbf{k}$ changes direction as well as another component of polarization vector. In synthesis, if $\epsilon_{L}$ is the polarization of the field going from left to right, the photon of the same polarization travelling from right to left has polarization $\epsilon_{R}$ modulus a phase $e^{i\phi}$.